# Extract views from an Activity and implement animation within OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm working on animations and I want to implement `OnClickListener` differently for cleaner code.

For example, I can do this.

Note: I want to run my work only when `active[0]` is `true`

MainActivity

```
 final Boolean[] active = {false};
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(active[0]){
                // do some work
            }else{
                Animation animPictureDeactiveLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.deactivate_picturebtn_onleft);
                Animation animVideoMiniLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.activate_videobtn_onleft);
                Animation animGifMiniLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.move_gifbtn_onleft);

                ImageView btnCameraPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
                ImageView btnCameraVid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureVideo);
                ImageView btnCameraGif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureGif);

                btnCameraPic.startAnimation(animPictureDeactiveLeft);
                btnCameraVid.startAnimation(animVideoMiniLeft);
                btnCameraGif.startAnimation(animGifMiniLeft);
                active[0] = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

This code works fine But I don't like this style of code.
So, I want to implement `OnClickListener` elsewhere.

I tried the following, but I don't know if this is a good way or not.
If not, please let me know what is best way.

TestClick

```
  public class TestClick extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
public static boolean bActive = false;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(bActive) {
        active();
    }else{
        Animation animPictureDeactiveLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TestClick.this, R.anim.deactivate_picturebtn_onleft);
        Animation animVideoMiniLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TestClick.this, R.anim.activate_videobtn_onleft);
        Animation animGifMiniLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TestClick.this, R.anim.move_gifbtn_onleft);

        ImageView btnCameraPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        ImageView btnCameraVid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureVideo);
        ImageView btnCameraGif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureGif);

        btnCameraPic.startAnimation(animPictureDeactiveLeft);
        btnCameraVid.startAnimation(animVideoMiniLeft);
        btnCameraGif.startAnimation(animGifMiniLeft);
        bActive = true;
    }
}

public void active(){

}

 }
```

MainActivity

```
       button.setOnClickListener(new TestClick(){
        public void active(){
            // do some work
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `TestClick extends AppCompatActivity`, then this is wrong.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new TestClick(){
    public void active(){
        // do some work
    }
});
```

Never `new` an Activity.

---

If you have an activity that implements the interface.

```
public class TestClick extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener
```

Then this is how you use it (assuming the button is in the current `TestClick` class).

```
button.setOnClickListener(TestClick.this);
```

And the overriden `onClick` within `this` class then gets called.

---

Or maybe `TestClick` shouldn't extend `AppCompatActivity` if it isn't *really* an Activity.

In that case, you'd want a simple class, not a full Activity

You'll also want to check the button that was clicked, possibly.

```
public class TestClick implements OnClickListener {
    private boolean bActive;
    private final Context mContext;

    public TestClick(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) { this.bActive = active; }
    public boolean isActive() { return this.bActive; }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.your_button_id) {
            if (this.isActive()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
```

And then you may use

```
button.setOnClickListener(new TestClick(MainActivity.this));
```

And note: `findViewById` cannot be resolved here, so you need to get another ways to reference your views.

Comment: @cricket007 where I implement my animations ? In on `TestClick` or in `MainActivity`

Comment: `TestClick` does not have any `onCreate` method. `findViewById` will fail, therefore you wouldn't be able to do any animation there. So make `MainActivity ... implements View.OnClickListener`

Comment: @cricket007 My main purpose is to organize animation code in separate class file. If I can't manage animation in `clickListener` I don't need to implement `OnClickListener` in `MainActivity`.

Comment: You **can** use a separate class, yes, **however**, I'm simply saying that you need to find some other way to get a "reference" to your views. (Because `TestClick` should not `extends AppCompatActivity`)

Comment: Only one thing is in my mind to organize animation in separate class file is that pass all views to class construct and create object in MainActivity. But I think passing too much views as argument is not a good way.

Comment: Any rough idea how can I do that ?

Comment: You could extend `ViewGroup` and wrap your several views with that, and handle your clicking and animation within there instead of the Activity.

Comment: when the button is clicked then animation apply on different views at same time is it possible in ViewGroup ?

Comment: And there is one other function as you see in my code. Animation apply first time second time it perform some work `//do some work`. I don't think I can get it by extended ViewGroup Can I ?

Comment: Your boolean flag is just a that... a flag. `ViewGroup` would not affect that. And, in theory, you should be able to do any animations within a group as you would within an Activity.

Comment: I really can't understand how I can implement my above code in `ViewGroup`. I search alot on creating custom `ViewGroup` but nothing found that fit on this scenario. Any Help ?

Comment: Here's the official docs on custom views. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html  I've also found several links on ViewGroup specifically